# How do you make patches in netlogo take on the colors of an imported shapefile?

Tags: gis, netlogo

```html
  '
                     fúè     G¾‹ðÑRÀ@ÑOïC@-ºü*½RÀÆOÙ§D@                                     H   1!Š´âÉRÀwš(yD@”Š¾6ìÈRÀIÊ;ŠãD@   F       2©Ì®~ÉRÀ6ÓœÄD@›rÇ˜sÉRÀ;=ºx·D@´µÉFbÉRÀü(I¿£D@}!YLKÉRÀ¬%”‰D@T-Bi@ÉRÀIë-}D@6j6ÉRÀ HQËqD@+f°’ÉRÀ²®‚9D@”Š¾6ìÈRÀí–[PD@ÁÀ–tîÈRÀ·cùB
D@X­#3ñÈRÀPYÈóíD@©³Î¶óÈRÀ| ¡_×D@}"ùÈRÀ¾…¥D@Ü¤G´þÈRÀ5µsD@oAÔÉRÀ ‚ŠWD@f¥Œ
ÉRÀaí&BD@®\¨ ÉRÀZ5šD@&Ùwo
ÉRÀMdÓ—ðD@à$_ÉRÀ:Ši©ÜD@ûÑPeÉRÀ9oæWÐD@ˆV2yÉRÀ€—ªÄªD@#‚üÉRÀwš(yD@Ñ‹;°0ÉRÀÛ`õê~D@!°¾4ÉRÀab÷D@¦dµÒAÉRÀWÃ>ƒD@æ‰º¾NÉRÀg+Ñš†D@ùl¼VÉRÀù½ˆD@á€%¸[ÉRÀøÁñ‰D@ù+‘hÉRÀl&7D@«x’U‚ÉRÀêº”D@·÷›ÉRÀ$i„hšD@¸»ùp¬ÉRÀz8—KœD@^é®¶ÉRÀê<`‡D@ùŸ/¸ÉRÀ›°D@×šÊÉRÀk–iËŸD@¨’ÒÖÈÉRÀ0¡8æÃD@·zÈÈÉRÀŒ2ÎÉD@&°Á(ÇÉRÀW4O9îD@Ë ‡EÆÉRÀî*æÑD@–"&ÄÉRÀÉÉŸ\7D@ÜæÏÔÂÉRÀ&1Ó•]D@€eX!ÃÉRÀÔ¨ÈíaD@¢â¤ÙÃÉRÀ»tøÀoD@ê)L±ÄÉRÀÑáü+zD@ÄÅÀÅÉRÀQB~D@¦½ÆÉRÀEöl.€D@ñ?J×ÉRÀÀÜ™±D@1!Š´âÉRÀá@h/ÔD@Þ$EÜÉRÀVŸSÙD@áÉ2ÕÉRÀ”ŸÀÛÞD@|98ÏÉRÀ$+Æ{ãD@´J¨ÇÉRÀX7zéD@ð˜¨ÖÀÉRÀ¼1šÎîD@£®ÃN¶ÉRÀ'á!÷D@Hnªk¸ÉRÀXð;ýD@¿RÏþ¶ÉRÀõÇˆíýD@µçÐ´ÉRÀ2eMÔýD@)€G¶³ÉRÀeÒãüD@p>Í°ÉRÀHúsD@…ÔÁ×¬ÉRÀøÁÅ;D@/ 0éªÉRÀÍ¶`MD@½"U©ÉRÀ/Ïá^]D@Ê0W§ÉRÀñNnD@=Ö=o¥ÉRÀFÆp D@Á¬£ÉRÀAÿ!D@Ìñ6ç¡ÉRÀ§Þ D@WùŸÉRÀ–Fuì°D@¦çá?žÉRÀÊ\"ìÀD@x2ÐbÉRÀP·NQÉD@{ÈKšÉRÀIÊ;ŠãD@2©Ì®~ÉRÀ6ÓœÄD@     È   ï Ÿ±ìÀRÀ¢ö«D@CU‚Fc¿RÀb|ßlD@   V       Gp‰[ÀRÀü¬C*WD@1êwð¿RÀ’¬ô.AD@Æ$¼ë¿RÀ…¡³J<D@I]"(¦¿RÀLÈ!íD@T)C¢¿RÀ)XAÄèD@q¼ñœ¿RÀïÌ¹ãD@ˆ´m¤–¿RÀôM@LßD@<¬dè¿RÀnÞ}"ÜD@Ã
KŠ¿RÀþÛ„ ÚD@š~lvƒ¿RÀƒ
ñ×D@î¬%|¿RÀxÓ«ÔD@¼pâ1x¿RÀØRðHÒD@„v¨t¿RÀbc<OÏD@U&‹q¿RÀ‹ŠM¯ÌD@›ÝU:n¿RÀ‘BÎcÉD@!õ4j¿RÀµsÿÃD@‹­3¶f¿RÀÅ&Ì¾D@}Èˆd¿RÀr™£¶¼D@CU‚Fc¿RÀÎBc\»D@¬èÈ¤g¿RÀÖàðµD@¿š+k¿RÀÃ2TÓ±D@÷2D½p¿RÀI™Ï·¬D@OÁØv¿RÀÀYãÆ¨D@M2ñ…}¿RÀ†š¸ò£D@ÎxýE¿RÀówœD@û»£ãž¿RÀïêwÛ’D@«1Ö¼¸¿RÀI+¯˜…D@UZ}Î¿RÀXþê€zD@­1iƒã¿RÀ Ê·yoD@›Â¿ö¿RÀ1ÿ]îdD@"
°;þ¿RÀë0È`D@KÀÞÀRÀ%é UD@NÍpcÀRÀÁŒ°SD@¢EØù0ÀRÀM¾´6+D@æÉÐ™NÀRÀŽY7ED@álÖñdÀRÀ?èO_àD@‚­ˆ@ÀRÀ~õ¹´D@ƒLL‰‚ÀRÀ)ö“²D@'}ÒÆ†ÀRÀ¢ö«D@bä¤"‰ÀRÀ˜q^¹D@Ê¸)§ˆÀRÀbmž¼D@RGaÎ‡ÀRÀ–®¿D@ÇYœ_‹ÀRÀ[þ]ÖD@(’À‹ÀRÀÛ^£ÚD@úSáÀRÀIÁäMÞD@K#¥ú–ÀRÀÆŠJ¾éD@ŒC¾6¦ÀRÀþµ{­ýD@BÉÔªÐÀRÀX’ý4D@út÷6ÒÀRÀFÆþ’8D@¬O×ÀRÀ×…‡æ?D@
QÛÀRÀ"¸4ÐBD@o$z+èÀRÀ·iÒÖSD@ï Ÿ±ìÀRÀH·:ÿYD@@ÌJ#èÀRÀÆ°9BbD@KŒâÀRÀ ‚hælD@÷‡ÙwßÀRÀ`WviD@ßËîÚÀRÀ×Æ¬¯dD@* ÜñÖÀRÀñQåjaD@×ÎJÒÀRÀ=ñŽ{_D@&‘IÍÀRÀ;2‹^D@SÆƒ—ÈÀRÀ?|C‚^D@T:ÑÄÀRÀeõ}_D@C,ÁÀRÀëú/Ü`D@ ’Tn¾ÀRÀ­ùybD@ŠD~”¼ÀRÀ]yê0dD@dn¨³ÀRÀi¢PblD@—Ru§ÀRÀ•Ò»
xD@'I £ÀRÀû­-ÚzD@È—ÐÃžÀRÀ½ôþ]}D@àÒä™ÀRÀ·ÅokD@‘Wn‘ÀRÀšLn‚D@
ö•ÀRÀ-Ly¨D@öŽ“æÀRÀ®Ñ,‹ªD@Ÿ‰ü¬ÀRÀ‰Âå|¬D@NBÒŠÀRÀ|ê®D@Õý,ˆÀRÀÂd+²D@¿ñ¶Ö„ÀRÀ¯>!®·D@ŽÙ ŸiÀRÀ>Ô" âD@zFÜ—\ÀRÀX/˜öD@dBÖÀOÀRÀ
0‹
```

[Boundary of Philadlephia shp file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK5FN.png) I am successfully able to import a shapefile into Netlogo. Someone told me that my foreach loop that applies my shp GIS layer is only creating lines in the drawing layer of NetLogo, not actually changing the patches themselves. How do I assign some component of the shapefile to the patches themselves for turtles to be able to assess them?

My code is

```
to setup
  clear-all
  create-turtles 10
  set-default-shape turtles "butterfly"
  ask turtles [set size 25]
  ;if pxcor = min-pxcor [die]]
  reset-ticks
  let view gis:load-dataset "City_Plan_Boundary.shp"
  gis:set-world-envelope gis:envelope-of view
  foreach gis:feature-list-of view
  [
    gis:set-drawing-color green
    gis:draw ? 1.0
  ]

end
```

thank you, ny help is appreciated. I am very new to netlogo.

Comment: What features are in the shapefile (eg population)? Generally, `gis:apply-coverage` is the appropriate primitive to assign a feature value to a patch. However, there are two other issues. First, patches are squares and the whole of each patch is the same colour. Second, the colour format from your GIS file is going to be different than the way NetLogo handles colours. So please also describe the format you have.

Comment: Hello Jen! Thank you for responding to my question. The gis file just provides boundaries of Philadelphia. I have my updated the post to include a picture of the shape file in netlogo.

Comment: Added note. I am not sure how to see what the variables are that need to be assigned to the patches.

Comment: If the shapefile has only the boundaries, what colour are you trying to 'take on'? There must be a field somewhere that has this colour.

Comment: Would it be smart to open the shp file with something like notepad++? I will attach the shp file to the post as well. There is an example of what I get when I open the shapefile attached.